# How do i put the gant title list below the chart?

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

Hi Guys here i have a Gantt Chart but i want to have it look similar like in the picture I post.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[%
 inline, 
 bar inline label anchor=west,
 bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white},
 bar/.append style={fill=cyan!90!black,}, 
 bar height=.8,]{0}{18}
 \gantttitlelist{0,...,18}{1}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J2}{3}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{18}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M2}{0}{5}
\ganttbar{J2}{5}{8}
\ganttbar{J1}{8}{12}
\ganttbar{}{12}{18}
\end{ganttchart}
\caption{To demonstrate Flow shop Scheduling}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: IT Should look like that]

Is it possible with `pgfgantt` or should I use other things? 
I just want to have the `gantttitlelist` below the chart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply move the `\gantttitlelist` line to the bottom. Vertical spacing of the title lines can be adjusted by adding `y unit title` to the `ganttchart` options. Adding a couple `draw=none` options and changing to sans serif typeface makes the result closer to the figure you show.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
{\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[%
 inline, 
 y unit title=1.1cm,
 canvas/.style={draw=none},
 title/.style={draw=none},
 bar inline label anchor=west,
 bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white},
 bar/.append style={fill=cyan!90!black,}, 
 bar height=.8,]{0}{18}
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J2}{3}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{18}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M2}{0}{5}
\ganttbar{J2}{5}{8}
\ganttbar{J1}{8}{12}
\ganttbar{}{12}{18}\\
\gantttitlelist{0,...,18}{1}
\end{ganttchart}
}
\caption{To demonstrate Flow shop Scheduling}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but the numbers are directly under the gantt chart, is there a possibility to put some space between the chart and the numbers form 0-18? verticalspace ?@erik

Comment: @MiloLi You can add something like `y unit title=1.1cm` to the options. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: is there a possibility to put the numbers more to the left, so that i can see that J2 on M2 starts on 5?

Comment: @MiloLi You need to reduce the size of `inner sep` for the label. Try changing the `bar inline label node` line to `bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white, inner sep=2pt}`

Comment: thank you man! but 5 is not under the line

Comment: ididnt mean the text(J2) inside, i mean the numbers below the gantt chart! 0 doesnt start where the gantt  chart begins! 5 must be under the dash, not next to the dash, do you know what i mean ?

Comment: @MiloLi I don't think Gantt charts are usually shown the way you describe, but you can shift the numbers by adding something like `title left shift=-0.9` to the options after `\begin{ganttchart}`

Comment: thank you! is there any possibility to put a t on the left side ? i tried it with ganttbar, but thats wrong, i just want a t under M1 and M2 as a text... can u give me an advise please?

Comment: @MiloLi I think you should post what you tried as a new question.